# select count(*) takes more time than than select(*) in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I have a pipelined function . I have two sql statements as below.
The first one is as select * from table
and the second one is a select count(*) from table.

```
SELECT *
  FROM table (es_feed_api_da.invoice_daily ('10-sep-2014'));

SELECT count(*)
 FROM table (es_feed_api_da.invoice_daily ('10-sep-2014'));
```

i am running the two queries in toad. 
I find that the second one (select count(*)) takes relatively more time than first one(select *)
Can someone please explain the reason to me..
Thanks

Comment: Explain plan would be useful.Also what does relatively mean exactly

Comment: Usually this happens when you don't actually select all result rows, but just the first X in your query tool. Then the first query is cancelled in the middle, whereas the count still needs to go over the whole table.

Comment: Try selecting count using one single non-null column; COUNT(single_column)

Comment: Mysql? Does this have anything to do with MySQL. You call PL/SQL function, this returns a table. Use DBMS_PROFILER to find out what happens during function execution.

Comment: This is an expected behavior with most of the GUI based client tools like **TOAD, SQL Developer, PL/SQL Developer** etc. `SELECT *` gives you only the first few rows and not all the rows. Scrolling down further will keep fetching more rows until you have fetched all the rows.

Answer (score 6):

> i am running the two queries in toad
>
> I find that the second one (select count(*)) takes relatively more time than first one(select *) Can someone please explain the reason to me.

It is quite obvious that `SELECT *` would be faster than `SELECT COUNT(*)` because you are executing it on **TOAD** which is a **GUI based client tool** and gives you only first few rows(like only `50 rows` in SQL Developer) when you simply **project/select** the rows. The time elapsed would keep increasing as and when you fetch more rows by **scrolling down** the query result.

On the other hand, when you do a `SELECT COUNT(*)`, it must count all the rows in the table as opposed to `SELECT *` which only returns the first few rows in TOAD.

I don't have TOAD, but I can demonstrate the behaviour in SQL Developer.

Output of `SELECT *` **ONLY first 50 rows**:

[image]

**After scrolling down to 500 rows:**

[image]

The time taken to fetch further rows will increase as and when you scroll down further.